# JQGrid form edit close form

Tags: jqgrid

Simple question:  How can one close ajqgrid edit form?  I close dialog boxes with the following:

```
    $("#submitDialog").dialog("close");
```

However, after inspecting the jqgrid form I'm having troubles finding the id to close.  Here is the editGridRow call that I use to create the form (this is for adding a row, but the same applies to editing a row).

```
    jQuery("#myGrid").editGridRow( "new", 
        {
    url:'addRow?type=' + gridForm.famousType,
    recreateForm:true,
    afterSubmit: function(responseData)
    {
        openDialog("#errorDialog", responseData.responseText);
        return [true, "true", 1];
    },
    errorTextFormat: function(serverresponse)
    {
        return serverresponse.responseText;
    },
    beforeSubmit: function(postdata, formid)
    {
        if(validationFunction == null)
        {
            return [true, ""];
        }
        return validationFunction.validate(postdata, formid);
    },
    beforeShowForm: (gridForm.beforeShowFormAdd)?gridForm.beforeShowFormAdd.run:null  //false or null?
        });
return false;
```

My guess is this is easy, I just haven't seen anything that says how to do it, including on the jqgrid wiki.  Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may not be the answer you're looking for, but since I couldn't find it myself I ended up using this workaround:

```
jQuery('.ui-jqdialog-titlebar-close').click();
```

Which will click the X button of the dialog, closing it.

Comment: Won't that click the 'X' of all dialog boxes open?  Normally I only have 1 form or dialog box open, but this business requirement forces us to bring up a grand total of 3 at one time, where the back two need to be closed (a form edit box and a normal jquery dialog box).  I can close the normal dialog box just fine, but not the form edit box :/

Comment: Well, if that's the case you can do something like this:

`jQuery('#editmodresult').find('.ui-jqdialog-titlebar-close').click(); ` by default the id of the form edit dialog is editmodresult, and that should avoid any other dialog closing too.

Comment: I'll give that a try on monday.  For now I have changed the order in the success function of when I call close and when I open the final dialog box.  This works, but I am always leery of hack jobs like this as a coworker could easily change the order on accident and cause a fairly large (to the user) issue.

Comment: I get your point, this is only a workaround I haven't found the proper way to do it myself.

Comment: I ended up sticking with your original solution of simply forcing a click of the 'X' and then opening up my next box immediately after.